What is the correct spacing for support posts when building cottage?
We are planning on building 20x24 or 24x32 vacation house. Its located in Ottawa region on Canadian shield (from what everyone is telling me). But it is very rocky there. Impossible to dig more than a foot before hitting rock. We want to build on the hill with simple sloped roof house. Hill has a significant angle. I have 2 questions I need advice on:

What is the correct spacing for support posts? I am planning on using 6x6 treated lumber, but I am debating spacing it 8ft or 6ft apart on center
What would be your recommendations for piers to create a solid concrete structure that would not shift, or sink down? I also want to have ability to adjust house level if I need to. Most neighbors just simply put concrete slabs right on the ground and put posts right on them. My friend dig as far as he could down and then poured concrete and inserted brackets for the posts. Contractor I am working with, recommended once I hit the rock to drill a hole in the rock and then put some rebar and then pour concrete. The reason was so if there is ground shift, the posts will stay together with the rock. Thanks everyone for your input!


https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/197008/18078 and https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/266783/18078 touch on anchoring short piers to rock, one on the Canadian shield, even. Though if you have a steep hill, some of your piers will likely be long.

As for the primary question of beam spacing, it's a lot like "how long is a piece of string" as it depends on the overall structural design. 4, 6, 8, 10, 12 or more can all work, with appropriate design. 6x6 is an OK post and a lousy excuse for a beam. 6x10 or 6x12 is a more reasonable beam (with the longer dimension making the beam deeper, not wider)
